# How disable and enable usb port via command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

How disable and enable usb port via command prompt? or using batch script ? or using vb script in windows 7?

Comment: There is the devcon command line tool for ms, it can disable the driver services for devices, not sure about disabling a usb hub http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272

Comment: See also the answers for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365223/disable-usb-storage-devices which provide detailed scripts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use batch which gives you a couple of options. You can edit the registry key to disable usb devices from being used

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "4" /f
```

To enable change value to `3`.

Or you can deny access to the files `Usbstor.pnf` and `Usbstor.inf`

```
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /d user
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf /d user
```

Where `user` is the user account that you want to deny access for.

To enable use

```
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /p user:R
cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf /p user:R
```

Both commands will need admin rights.

Hope this helps

Comment: HOW CAN I ENABLE AFTER THIS?

Comment: I have edited to show how to enable, and there's no need for CAPS LOCK TO BE ON! :)

Comment: this commands does't work in windows 7 (cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /d user / cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf /d user / cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /p user:R / cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf /p user:R

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at `devcon` command. Available freely on microsoft site, for win7+ windows.

Comment: Note that the ia64 version does not work on Windows 7 64-bit.  You need to use this version from Windows Server: http://delphintipz.blogspot.com/2012/07/disable-failed-no-devices-disabled.html instructions to use here: http://ccm.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line

Comment: [ia64 != x86_64](http://superuser.com/questions/276994/difference-between-ia64-and-x64)...

Comment: Yeah well, you need the other version on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Is there a way to get this without installing a 2 GB+ dev kit?

Comment: Earlier, it was available for download as a standalone binary. (I have an old copy downloaded locally, which I keep copying to other systems as required.) Now apparently, now it comes only as a part of dev-kit. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe) may help you...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I use a solution that takes the best of the two previous answers:

1º-We disable the functionality that allow us to detect new external storage devices:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "4" /f
```

2º-We remove all the drivers of USB devices installed on the PC (This will also eliminate the possibility of using keyboard and mouse, but only momentarily):

```
devcon.exe remove *USB*
```

3º- We re-scan the connected USB devices, so that Windows will automatically install the drivers of devices different than external storage (eg Mouse, keyboard ...), thus obtaining the desired result:

```
devcon.exe rescan
```

4º- If we want to re-allow the use of external storage devices in our PC, we must use the command:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "3" /f
```

PD: Every command will need admin rights

Answer (score 0):

I use USBDeview. See documentation and examples to use it. Easy and works fine. Now i'm using USBTreeView [sieber webpage download link](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).