# How to disable a storage device(usb) not the usb ports

Tags: java, usb, device

I googled for this but didn't find any related thread.
How can we disable a particular device so that it could not be connected via USB like using any virus or any program(preferably in java) while the USB ports should be opened for all other USB devices, i.e., by making changes in USB device not in USB ports.
Thanks !

Comment: Take a look at the answers for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365223/disable-usb-storage-devices and see if that fits your needs.