# how to disable USB port using java

Tags: java, windows

This syntax system("reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f");
i use in c++ but how to use disable usb in java i try but it gives a error on it that exception error.

Comment: What your try and what error, post the whole stacktrace. And why is this tagged Linux?

Comment: Check out this answer. It talks about how to modify the registry with Java code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365223/disable-usb-storage-devices for additional information about various ways to disable a USB Storage device.